# Issue with Chartboost. Unable to load Ad

Tags: android, chartboost

I integrated Chartboost. After run the project when i click on button to show add. than after sometime log cat shows this type of message: "Unable to resolve host "www.chartboost.com": No address associated with host name", I don't know which type of error occurred? and i declared Internet and WiFi Permission in Manifest. If you have any idea related to it, than please share with me. Thanks.